# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line (can't find a solution in the other posts)

Tags: php, html, css

i have seen the previous post on the argument, but i haven't find a solution. I have this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file" in the code, but i can't understand why. Here the code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>


<?php global $thr_sidebar_opts; ?>
<?php if ( $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] == 'left' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>

<div class="main_content_wrapper">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">
    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
    {
        bcn_display();
    }?>
</div>
    <div class="entry-header">      
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <?php if( thr_get_option('page_show_fimg') && has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
    <div class="entry-image">
        <?php $img_size = $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] ? 'thr-layout-a' : 'thr-layout-a-nosid'; ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail($img_size); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
    </div>

<div class="clear"></div>   

</article><!-- #post -->

<?php if( thr_get_option('page_show_comments') ) : ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] == 'right' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>

</section>

<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

Comment: No syntax errors here - is this the whole file? Have you tried using a linter?

Comment: No, i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the while loop. You need to add  before you get th sidebar as below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $thr_sidebar_opts; ?>
<?php if ( $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] == 'left' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>

<div class="main_content_wrapper">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">
<?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
{
    bcn_display();
}?>
</div>
<div class="entry-header">      
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>

<?php if( thr_get_option('page_show_fimg') && has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
<div class="entry-image">
    <?php $img_size = $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] ? 'thr-layout-a' : 'thr-layout-a-nosid'; ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail($img_size); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>   

</article><!-- #post -->

<?php if( thr_get_option('page_show_comments') ) : ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ( $thr_sidebar_opts['use_sidebar'] == 'right' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>

</section>

<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i have the sidebar below. http://ilmanualedelgiocatore.it/contatti/

Comment: nots ure what you mean.. can you explain a bit more